# Security Concerns About Building A Website

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am new in coding family ,so i am worry bit about things a coder should keep in mind as security concerns, so i come here hoping someone will help me.
i have learned all things which are necessary for building a website (Html,css,js,jquery,php,mysql).i know some basic tricks thanks to w3schools. but i need someone who can share his/her knowledge and practical experience, because i am really concern about security side.
i don,t want any security codes just things i should keep in mind.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are thousands of security problems and there respective solutions. I don't think all of those can be answered here.

Comment: This is like saying "I'm new to carpentry, I need to know all the things a house builder should keep in mind". You can't learn everything from a simple question here, it takes years of experience.

Comment: Welcome to the world of coding. As your new here, this habit can be broken easily. Do **not** use w3fools

Comment: @Barmar haha yeah right sir , but you know their is a saying,if you want to be a master , follow a master, thats why i need a footprint :) but thanks for your time

Comment: That's right. So become an apprentice to an experienced website designer. You can't do it by asking questions here.

Comment: @AhmedRaza yeah i totally understand this  and thanks for your time and advice i will now look out for all those point thanks bro.

Comment: @Barmar roger that sir.

Comment: @DarylGill  ohk thank you, from now on wards  no more w3fools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are thousands of security problems and there respective solutions. I don't think all of those can be answered here.

But as you are a beginner here are few things that you should learn:

- Server side vs Client side validation
- SQL Injections
- Cross-site request forgeries
- Cross-site scripting
- Protocols i.e HTTP and HTTPS
- Authentications and authorizations

As I said earlier there are thousands and thousands of techniques to hack into your code and there solutions. All can't be mentioned here. It takes years to learn everything.

In some cases, the problems will apply to only your own use cases, for which you'll have to be open minded and think the solutions according to the use case while building your website.

Answer (score -1):

**Some security issues, you have to prevent these areas (take care of these areas)**

1. SQL Injections
2. Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
3. Broken Authentication & Session Management
4. Insecure Direct Object References
5. Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
6. Keep software up to date
7. Server side validation/form validation
8. File uploads
9. Email Form Header Injection
10. Malicious File Upload and Execution